# OpenXMl Bulleted List with mUltiple Bullet Charcter.?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

My Expected out put is

```
● AA 
► BBB 
■ CCC
```

I have tried a lot and but gets the output like this

```
● AA
● BBB
● CCC
```

My code is

```
Document document1 = new Document();

document1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");

Body body1 = new Body();      


Paragraph paragraph3 = new Paragraph();

ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new ParagraphProperties();
ParagraphStyleId paragraphStyleId1 = new ParagraphStyleId(){ Val = "ListParagraph" };
Shading shading1 = new Shading(){ Val = ShadingPatternValues.Clear, Color = "auto", Fill = "Blue" };
SpacingBetweenLines spacingBetweenLines1 = new SpacingBetweenLines();
Justification justification1 = new Justification(){ Val = JustificationValues.Left };

NumberingProperties numberingProperties1 = new NumberingProperties();
NumberingLevelReference numberingLevelReference1 = new NumberingLevelReference(){ Val = 0 };
NumberingId numberingId1 = new NumberingId(){ Val = 1 };

numberingProperties1.Append(numberingLevelReference1);
numberingProperties1.Append(numberingId1);

paragraphProperties1.Append(paragraphStyleId1);
paragraphProperties1.Append(shading1);
paragraphProperties1.Append(spacingBetweenLines1);
paragraphProperties1.Append(justification1);
paragraphProperties1.Append(numberingProperties1);

Run run3 = new Run();

Text text2 = new Text();
text2.Text = "AA";

run3.Append(runProperties2);
run3.Append(text2);

paragraph3.Append(paragraphProperties1);
paragraph3.Append(run3);

Paragraph paragraph4 = new Paragraph();

ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties2 = new ParagraphProperties();
ParagraphStyleId paragraphStyleId2 = new ParagraphStyleId(){ Val = "ListParagraph" };
Shading shading2 = new Shading(){ Val = ShadingPatternValues.Clear, Color = "auto", Fill = "Blue" };
SpacingBetweenLines spacingBetweenLines2 = new SpacingBetweenLines();
Justification justification2 = new Justification(){ Val = JustificationValues.Left };

NumberingProperties numberingProperties2 = new NumberingProperties();
NumberingLevelReference numberingLevelReference2 = new NumberingLevelReference(){ Val = 0 };
NumberingId numberingId2 = new NumberingId(){ Val = 2 };

numberingProperties2.Append(numberingLevelReference2);
numberingProperties2.Append(numberingId2);

paragraphProperties2.Append(paragraphStyleId2);
paragraphProperties2.Append(shading2);
paragraphProperties2.Append(spacingBetweenLines2);
paragraphProperties2.Append(justification2);
paragraphProperties2.Append(numberingProperties2);

Run run4 = new Run();

Text text3 = new Text();
text3.Text = "BBB";

run4.Append(runProperties3);
run4.Append(text3);

paragraph4.Append(paragraphProperties2);
paragraph4.Append(run4);

Paragraph paragraph5 = new Paragraph();

ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties3 = new ParagraphProperties();
ParagraphStyleId paragraphStyleId3 = new ParagraphStyleId(){ Val = "ListParagraph" };
Shading shading3 = new Shading(){ Val = ShadingPatternValues.Clear, Color = "auto", Fill = "Blue" };
SpacingBetweenLines spacingBetweenLines3 = new SpacingBetweenLines();
Justification justification3 = new Justification(){ Val = JustificationValues.Left };

NumberingProperties numberingProperties3 = new NumberingProperties();
NumberingLevelReference numberingLevelReference3 = new NumberingLevelReference(){ Val = 0 };
NumberingId numberingId3 = new NumberingId(){ Val = 3 };

numberingProperties3.Append(numberingLevelReference3);
numberingProperties3.Append(numberingId3);

paragraphProperties3.Append(paragraphStyleId3);
paragraphProperties3.Append(shading3);
paragraphProperties3.Append(spacingBetweenLines3);
paragraphProperties3.Append(justification3);
paragraphProperties3.Append(numberingProperties3);

Run run5 = new Run();

Text text4 = new Text();
text4.Text = "CCC";

run5.Append(runProperties4);
run5.Append(text4);

paragraph5.Append(paragraphProperties3);
paragraph5.Append(run5);

body1.Append(paragraph1);
body1.Append(paragraph2);
body1.Append(paragraph3);
body1.Append(paragraph4);
body1.Append(paragraph5);

document1.Append(body1);
document1.Append(openXmlUnknownElement2);

mainDocumentPart1.Document = document1;

Numbering numbering1 = new Numbering();

numbering1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");

AbstractNum abstractNum1 = new AbstractNum(){ AbstractNumberId = 0 };
MultiLevelType multiLevelType1 = new MultiLevelType(){ Val = MultiLevelValues.HybridMultilevel };

Level level1 = new Level(){ LevelIndex = 0 };
StartNumberingValue startNumberingValue1 = new StartNumberingValue(){ Val = 1 };
NumberingFormat numberingFormat1 = new NumberingFormat(){ Val = NumberFormatValues.Bullet };
LevelText levelText1 = new LevelText(){ Val = "●" };
LevelJustification levelJustification1 = new LevelJustification(){ Val = LevelJustificationValues.Left };

NumberingSymbolRunProperties numberingSymbolRunProperties1 = new NumberingSymbolRunProperties();
RunFonts runFonts6 = new RunFonts(){ Hint = FontTypeHintValues.Default, Ascii = "Arial", HighAnsi = "Arial" };

numberingSymbolRunProperties1.Append(runFonts6);

level1.Append(startNumberingValue1);
level1.Append(numberingFormat1);
level1.Append(levelText1);
level1.Append(levelJustification1);
level1.Append(numberingSymbolRunProperties1);

abstractNum1.Append(multiLevelType1);
abstractNum1.Append(level1);

NumberingInstance numberingInstance1 = new NumberingInstance(){ NumberID = 1 };
AbstractNumId abstractNumId1 = new AbstractNumId(){ Val = 0 };

numberingInstance1.Append(abstractNumId1);

AbstractNum abstractNum2 = new AbstractNum(){ AbstractNumberId = 1 };
MultiLevelType multiLevelType2 = new MultiLevelType(){ Val = MultiLevelValues.HybridMultilevel };

Level level2 = new Level(){ LevelIndex = 0 };
StartNumberingValue startNumberingValue2 = new StartNumberingValue(){ Val = 1 };
NumberingFormat numberingFormat2 = new NumberingFormat(){ Val = NumberFormatValues.Bullet };
LevelText levelText2 = new LevelText(){ Val = "►" };
LevelJustification levelJustification2 = new LevelJustification(){ Val = LevelJustificationValues.Left };

NumberingSymbolRunProperties numberingSymbolRunProperties2 = new NumberingSymbolRunProperties();
RunFonts runFonts7 = new RunFonts(){ Hint = FontTypeHintValues.Default, Ascii = "Arial", HighAnsi = "Arial" };

numberingSymbolRunProperties2.Append(runFonts7);

level2.Append(startNumberingValue2);
level2.Append(numberingFormat2);
level2.Append(levelText2);
level2.Append(levelJustification2);
level2.Append(numberingSymbolRunProperties2);

abstractNum2.Append(multiLevelType2);
abstractNum2.Append(level2);

NumberingInstance numberingInstance2 = new NumberingInstance(){ NumberID = 2 };
AbstractNumId abstractNumId2 = new AbstractNumId(){ Val = 6 };

numberingInstance2.Append(abstractNumId2);

AbstractNum abstractNum3 = new AbstractNum(){ AbstractNumberId = 2 };
MultiLevelType multiLevelType3 = new MultiLevelType(){ Val = MultiLevelValues.HybridMultilevel };

Level level3 = new Level(){ LevelIndex = 0 };
StartNumberingValue startNumberingValue3 = new StartNumberingValue(){ Val = 1 };
NumberingFormat numberingFormat3 = new NumberingFormat(){ Val = NumberFormatValues.Bullet };
LevelText levelText3 = new LevelText(){ Val = "■" };
LevelJustification levelJustification3 = new LevelJustification(){ Val = LevelJustificationValues.Left };

NumberingSymbolRunProperties numberingSymbolRunProperties3 = new NumberingSymbolRunProperties();
RunFonts runFonts8 = new RunFonts(){ Hint = FontTypeHintValues.Default, Ascii = "Arial", HighAnsi = "Arial" };

numberingSymbolRunProperties3.Append(runFonts8);

level3.Append(startNumberingValue3);
level3.Append(numberingFormat3);
level3.Append(levelText3);
level3.Append(levelJustification3);
level3.Append(numberingSymbolRunProperties3);

abstractNum3.Append(multiLevelType3);
abstractNum3.Append(level3);

NumberingInstance numberingInstance3 = new NumberingInstance(){ NumberID = 3 };
AbstractNumId abstractNumId3 = new AbstractNumId(){ Val = 3 };

numberingInstance3.Append(abstractNumId3);

numbering1.Append(abstractNum1);
numbering1.Append(numberingInstance1);
numbering1.Append(abstractNum2);
numbering1.Append(numberingInstance2);
numbering1.Append(abstractNum3);
numbering1.Append(numberingInstance3);

numberingDefinitionsPart1.Numbering = numbering1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the NumberingInstances AFTER you have appended ALL the AbstractNumbers. They shouldn't be between them.